# how to stop a spinner from automatically selecting an option?

Tags: android, spinner

i have a spinner in an app im doing, and when it goes to OnItemSelcted it automatically selects the first option, how do i stop that in a simple way?

```
 spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){


                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view,
                                int pos, long id) {
```

Comment: that's the default behavior. what else you expect???

Comment: This can be useful for you, I had the same questions a time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167162/onnavigationitemselected-in-actionbar-is-being-called-at-startup-how-can-avoid-i

Comment: Better use popup menu instead of spinner.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked many times on SO and elsewhere. For example:

[onNavigationItemSelected in ActionBar is being called at startup how can avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167162/onnavigationitemselected-in-actionbar-is-being-called-at-startup-how-can-avoid-i?lq=1)

[Infinite loop when using onNavigationItemSelected and invalidateOptionsMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236338/infinite-loop-when-using-onnavigationitemselected-and-invalidateoptionsmenu)

[Activity loop using onNavigationItemSelected on an ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094149/activity-loop-using-onnavigationitemselected-on-an-actionbar)

Several answers and comments suggest ignoring (some) callbacks. This would work for very simple uses, but it ignores the fact that most people asking this question want a *menu* not the spinner-based tab-like navigation provided by the standard ActionBar in list mode. Some comments suggest using a PopupMenu, but none that I saw provided details. So here's what to do:

1. Create the View that will be displayed in the ActionBar and on which the user will click to see the menu:

   ```
   View view = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_view, null);
   ```
2. Create a PopupMenu anchored to that View:

   ```
   PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, view);
   popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, popup.getMenu());
   ```
3. Add an `OnClickListener` to the View that shows the PopupMenu:

   ```
   view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           popup.show();
       }
   });
   ```
4. Add an `OnMenuItemClickListener` to the PopupMenu to receive notification when the user selects from the menu:

   ```
   popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           return true;
       }
   });
   ```
5. Finally, use the following to configure the ActionBar in your Activity:

   ```
   ActionBar ab = this.getActionBar();
   ab.setCustomView(view);
   ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
   ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
   ```

One comment is that it can be a bit tricky to get the main View styled to match the default ActionBar. Try investigating the following style resources:

```
@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.ActionBar.Title
@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse
@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title
@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse
```

Otherwise you need at least the right color and text size probably medium. The view itself should obviously `fill_parent` and have `center_vertical` gravity.

'Nuff said.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean variable to check if it is first time, do not execute the code.
Execute your code second time, otherwise it is the default behavior.

Comment: Like this one onItemSelected(){ if(firstTime){ firstTime = false; return true;}}

Answer (score 0):

> how do i stop that in a simple way?

You don't. A `Spinner` *always* has a selection, unless the adapter is empty and no selection is possible. Your app needs to *always* handle a selection, by one means or another.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `if` Statement to check the position of the item. Add a hint on item at position 0, when item other than position 0 is selected then perform your function as shown below:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        if (position != 0)
        {
            String val = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            // Toast.makeText(activity, formid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```